# Invalid column names in Mongo - affects performance

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I use MongoChef for querying on MongoDB. We currently have clustered Mongo environment with 3 shards and occassionally some of our members use invalid column names while queryingthe MongoDB. For ex: instead of 
- running a find on "_id" column, accidentally someone use "id" (without underscore)

Mongo try to process these queries  without throwing any error and takes hours to run these queries. Also we noticed that these queries are affecting the Mongo health as such.. available Ticket count drops and overall response time for other VALID queries gets impacted.

Is there a way to prevent this scenario in Mongo? 
- Can we run a offline job in Mongo to kill long running queries?
- Can mongo send notification upon encountering long running queries?

We've more than 40 member team and its difficult to prevent these kind of invalid queries, because someone may accidentally use "id" in place of "_id" , or flip the characters in column name that ends up with similar impact.

I would like to know if you're using some mechanism to prevent this?

Comment: Also, Somewhat related snack size summary: [Finding and terminating long-running operations in MongoDB](https://blog.mlab.com/2014/02/mongodb-currentop-killop/)

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer based on above links. This community rocks!